# Is "targetedly" (i.e. the adverb of targeted) a word?

Tags: adverbs

I want to convey that an action is done with a certain target in mind. Is "targetedly" (as the adverb of "targeted") the correct word? Several spellchecks don't know the word.

For example: "He targetedly shot the football at his teammate's face." As opposed to "He shot the football at his teammate's face by accident."

(I know "on purpose" would be a good/better fit here.)

If not, is there a synonym of this word with the same meaning?

Comment: It's not a word.  The word you want is probably "deliberately".

Comment: He targeted the kick or shot at his teammate's face. apostrophe s.

Comment: @Lambie thanks. I generally know the difference if you'd ask me which to use but sometimes confuse them when not thinking about it.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Just a word of advice for the future, if you get stuck on a word or can't think of one, don't just make one up. Use an online dictionary with a thesaurus feature.  For example, you already know the word "accidentally", and what you want to find is the antonym (the opposite). You can find these using a thesaursus. [see an example](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/thesaurus/accidentally)

Comment: @BillyKerr targetedly is a literal translation from German where the term exists and means exactly what I'm trying to convey. I wasn't sure whether the word exists, it does seem understandable but the only google hits where papers with non-english author names - which seemed like a bad sign. Using opposites is a good idea, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @DonQuiKong- that's really very interesting - but yeah, don't do that either. LOL. English is a Germanic language but it's fairly different from German, and words don't always translate well directly from one language into the other, even if they do kind of make sense.  Remember also that English, unlike German, also uses a lot of Latin/French derived vocabulary, particularly for abstract concepts, rather than just taking existing English/Germanic words and stringing them altogether in new combinations (which the Germans absolutely love to do).

Comment: @BillyKerr can't help it, I knew what I wanted to express and the only word that came to mind was a German word. And it seemed to translate well. And English does know "targeted" with the same meaning. Someone just forgot listing the corresponding adverb in the dictionary ;)

Comment: What is that German word, BTW? gezielt?  You could say "He aimed the ball at his teammate's face."

Comment: @TimR yes, gezielt. The football example wasn't great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Targetedly' is not a recognised adverb. Try:

- Deliberately
- Intentionally
- Willfully
- Purposefully
- Consciously

Otherwise, just use 'targeted' as the verb:

> He targeted the football at his teammate's face.

---

You've added in a comment that you are looking for adverbs you could ascribe to a machine.

My choice would be *selectively*, which suggests a selection was made but it is much colder and doesn't involve any words that imply human thinking (like decision or will).

Otherwise, you could perhaps consider:

- Algorithmically
- Systematically
- Automatically

These sound more robotic, like the product of a computer's reasoning.

Comment: Thank you. The sentence I'm building relates to a machine, i.e. something without a will. It uses an algorithm that does something /targetedly/, meaning it's not just a side effect. For example, a vacuum robot may target places with high amounts of dirt or may just vacuum all places equally. Then the vacuum /targetedly/ removed the dirt in the first case while it /non-targetedly/ removed the dirt in the second case. But the vacuum neither has a will nor a conscience nor an intention nor does it deliberate.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Maybe add that into your question.  But I've updated my answer.

Comment: I didn't want to invalidate your answer by changing the question. "Selectively" is great, exactly the word im looking for.